# I want to position "components" in a bootstrap container?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

[This is what the code will display now:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptM6i.png)

[This is what I *want* it to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yRXR.png)

The positioning of the components is what's driving me nuts. I can not seem to get the "**Gender:**" , "**Gender RadioButton list**" , "**Age:**" , "**Age RadioButton list**" to display in 4 columns on a single row.
There are going to be several different survey questions, so I do need to make the display based on CSS.

How, (or where) can learn how to properly use the  and <Div class="col"???>? It's like learning Klingon to me.

```css
.form-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  border: 0.375rem solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: #339900 0.625rem 1.25rem 1.25rem -0.625rem;
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
  width: 75%;
  height: 40%;
}

.form-container .RadioArray {
  width: 40rem;
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 0.938rem;
  padding-right: 0.938rem;
  padding-top: 0.313rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.313rem;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 0.125rem;
  border-color: #000000;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  text-align: center;
  */
}

.form-container .RadioBox {
  width: fit-content;
  padding-left: 0.938rem;
  padding-right: 0.938rem;
  padding-top: 0.313rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.313rem;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 0.125rem;
  border-color: #009900;
  background-color: #B3FFB2;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  font-family: Cabin SemiBold, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-container .spread {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
  font-family: Valken, serif;
  color: #8A8A8A;
  height: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.150rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: centre;
}

h4 {
  font-family: fantasy, "Cabin Medium";
  font-size: 1.50rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap Font Icon CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="PlayRoom.css" type="text/css">
  <title>PlayRoom</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Optional</h4>
  <div class="form-container">

    <div class="RadioArray">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="spread">Gender</span>
          </div>
          <div class="RadioBox">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="gender1" name="cGender" value="No Answer" checked>
              <label class "form-check-label" for="gender1">Declined</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="gender2" name="cGender" value="Male">
              <label class "form-check-label" for="gender3">Male</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="gender3" name="cGender" value="Female">
              <label class "form-check-label" for="gender3">Female</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="gender4" name="cGender" value="Neutral">
              <label class "form-check-label" for="gender4">Neutral</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="spread">Age</span>
          </div>
          <div class="RadioBox">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="cAge1" name="cAgeGroup" value="No Answer" checked />
              <label class "form-check-label" for='cAge1'>Declined</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="cAge2" name="cAgeGroup" value="under 19" />
              <label class "form-check-label" for='cAge2'>under 19</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="cAge3" name="cAgeGroup" value="19-40" />
              <label class "form-check-label" for='cAge3'>19 to 40</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="cAge4" name="cAgeGroup" value="over 40" />
              <label class "form-check-label" for='cAge4'>Over 40</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this approach on your html -

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
    Gender:
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    "Gender RadioButton list"
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    Age:
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
   "Age RadioButton list" 
</div>
```

Explanation: a row can be divided into 12 cols and based on your requirement you need 2 cols for the headings "gender" & "age" which won't need much space hence we are using col-md-2 , then the list requires a bit more space that's why we use col-md-4. And, if you notice all the cols add up to 12.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is based on 12 columns. Containers are a block with/without margin depending on if you choose `container` or `container-fluid` Rows are `row` and a row can have columns like `col-6` is size columns taken. You don't have to have ALL 12 columns.

You had some class without the = like `class "someclass"` also.

This is not 100% you desire but that is really just the colors/style visually to get you started.

You had too much CSS custom perhaps. Bootstrap has classes for padding `p-3` for example, border `border` etc. and some additional can also probably be removed.

As for your question reference the "grid" system of bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

For example I used `col-6` but you might just need `col` so when you get 3 you don't have to change `col-6` to `col-4`

```css
.survey-block {
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  border: 0.375rem solid;
}

.survey-group {
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.form-container .RadioArray {
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 0.125rem;
}

.h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.50rem;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<body>
  <div class="survey-block container text-center p-4 bg-info">
    <div class="h3">Optional</div>
    <div class="form-container container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <span class="h3 p-2 col-5 text-end">Gender:</span>
            <div class="col-7 RadioBox p-3 border border-dark survey-group">
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="gender1" name="cGender" value="No Answer" checked>
                <label class "form-check-label" for="gender1">Declined</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="gender2" name="cGender" value="Male">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gender3">Male</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="gender3" name="cGender" value="Female">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gender3">Female</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="gender4" name="cGender" value="Neutral">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gender4">Neutral</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <span class="col-5 h3  p-1 text-end">Age:</span>
            <div class="col-7 RadioBox p-3 border border-dark survey-group">
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="cAge1" name="cAgeGroup" value="No Answer" checked />
                <label class="form-check-label" for='cAge1'>Declined</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="cAge2" name="cAgeGroup" value="under 19" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for='cAge2'>under 19</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="cAge3" name="cAgeGroup" value="19-40" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for='cAge3'>19 to 40</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="cAge4" name="cAgeGroup" value="over 40" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for='cAge4'>Over 40</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```